# Passing value with a button in the form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass a value through clicking a button that is inside a form.

Below is my code:

```
 <form action=deleteProduct.php?skuCode=".$row["skuCode"]." method=get><input type=submit name=delete value=Delete></form>
```

But from the above code I wanted to get the skuCode=".$row["skuCode"].". Instead the value passed was delete=Delete.

How should I amend my code to get the skuCode in deleteProduct.php.

Comment: Can you show more code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may be outputting it all in a single `echo`. In this case, the solution will require a few extra lines, so it'd probably be best to change it to:

```
//close off PHP if required 
?>

<form action="deleteProduct.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['skuCode'] ?>" name="skuCode">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>

<?php 
//resume PHP if need be
```

Something to that effect should work.

I'm not 100% sure how your `$row["skuCode"]` part works.. I guess it's PHP? Either way, just insert the value however you need to, but that HTML should do it.

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/rt9yc/

In this jsfiddle, when I click on the `delete` button with the network tools open in my inspector I see a request for: `deleteProduct.php?skuCode=testSKU` ("testSKU" being the dummy SKU I was using in the fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<form action="deleteProduct.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["skuCode"] ?>" name="skuCode">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

In the `deleteProduct.php` page, you can access the value by using `$_GET['skuCode']`